# real intersection of 2 paths in android ( new path )

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I try to intersect 2 paths in Android. This works fine in the first attempt. When I am zooming into the drawing ( canvas.scale() ) then the intersected shape is unprecise  and ugly.
Does anyone know howto solve my problem ?

I like to intersect the Red Square with the Blue rectangle, which is inside the Red Square.
[image]

With my Code the result is the unprecise green intersection when scaling:

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);

canvas.scale(20,20);
Paint paint1 = new Paint();
paint1.setColor(Color.RED); paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
Path path=new Path();
path.moveTo(10, 10); path.lineTo(20, 10); path.lineTo(20, 20); path.lineTo(10, 20); path.close();
//canvas.drawPath(path, paint1);
Path path2=new Path();
path2.moveTo(15, 10); path2.lineTo(20, 10); path2.lineTo(20, 20); path.close();
paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
//canvas.drawPath(path2, paint1);

Region clip = new Region();
    clip.set((int)0,(int)0, (int)300,(int)300);
Region region1 = new Region();
region1.setPath(path, clip);
Region region2 = new Region();
region2.setPath(path2, clip);
region1.op(region2, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

Path pnew=region1.getBoundaryPath();
paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawPath(pnew, paint1);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution is as follow. 
Before I intersect my pathes I scale them up . After intersection I scale them down. I don't know if thats a good solution, but it worked for me. Its also fast. In my example I intersect a rounded path with a owncreated pattern ( stripes ). It looks still good when scaling :-)

[image]

[image]

Here my Code :

```
    Path mypath=new Path(<desiredpath to fill with a pattern>);
    String sPatternType=cpath.getsPattern();

    Path pathtempforbounds=new Path(cpath.getPath());
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
     if (sPatternType.equals("1")){
         turnPath(pathtempforbounds, -45);
     }
     pathtempforbounds.computeBounds(rectF, true);

     float ftop=rectF.top;
     float fbottom=rectF.bottom;
     float fleft=rectF.left;
     float fright=rectF.right;
     float xlength=fright-fleft;

     Path pathpattern=new Path();

     float ypos=ftop;
     float xpos=fleft;

     float fStreifenbreite=4f;

     while(ypos<fbottom){
         pathpattern.moveTo(xpos,ypos);
         xpos=xpos+xlength;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         ypos=ypos+fStreifenbreite;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         xpos=xpos-xlength;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         ypos=ypos-fStreifenbreite;
         pathpattern.lineTo(xpos, ypos);
         pathpattern.close();
         ypos=ypos+2*fStreifenbreite;

     }

     // Original vergrössern

     scalepath(pathpattern,10);
     scalepath(mypath,10);

     if (sPatternType.equals("1")){
         Matrix mdrehen=new Matrix();
         RectF bounds=new RectF();
         pathpattern.computeBounds(bounds, true);
         mdrehen.postRotate(45, (bounds.right + bounds.left)/2,(bounds.bottom + bounds.top)/2);
         pathpattern.transform(mdrehen);
     }

     RectF rectF2 = new RectF();
     mypath.computeBounds(rectF2, true);

     Region clip = new Region();
     clip.set((int)(rectF2.left-100f),(int)(rectF2.top -100f), (int)(rectF2.right+100f),(int)( rectF2.bottom+100f));
     Region region1 = new Region();
     region1.setPath(pathpattern, clip);

     Region region2 = new Region();
     region2.setPath(mypath, clip);

     region1.op(region2, Region.Op.INTERSECT);


     Path pnew=region1.getBoundaryPath();


     scalepath(pnew, 0.1f);
     cpath.setPathpattern(pnew);




public void turnPath(Path p,int idegree){
     Matrix mdrehen=new Matrix();
     RectF bounds=new RectF();
     p.computeBounds(bounds, true);
     mdrehen.postRotate(idegree, (bounds.right + bounds.left)/2,(bounds.bottom + bounds.top)/2);
     p.transform(mdrehen);
}

public void scalepath(Path p,float fscale){
     Matrix mverkleinern=new Matrix();
     mverkleinern.preScale(fscale,fscale);
     p.transform(mverkleinern);
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, the only question is how does the region intersection works, i.e. does it create a temporary bitmap which in your case can be 10x bigger than the screen? If not then I may use this solution too for smoothening the edges. The real big problem is how to extract the points of this resulting path and save it, which I am attempting here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49239/converting-a-2d-curve-into-points-for-data-storage

Comment: Your solution solves my problem. So if you post this answer in the link I posted above, I will reward you 300 points!

Answer (score 0):

The region intersection, union etc, produces a NON anti-aliased path, unfortunately!

Depends what you want to do with this, you can just add shapes to the same path, but set path to

```
myPath.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
```

In this way when you draw it, you can create a "hole" in a shape.

Comment: Thank you very much. But this didn't help. I understand a bit more regarding the pathes, I guess :-) When drawing a path with moveto,lineto etc... a bitmap is created, which looks ugly when scaling. I post my solution with scaling befor intersection.